# Getting a list of functions and procedure signature from oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is there any query which can provide me signature details of a Function/Procedure. I am looking at return type, function name, argument types, whether IN/OUT/INOUT.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819447/get-a-list-of-all-functions-and-procedures-in-an-oracle-database) thread, but it provides only names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little script that produces PL/SQL function prototypes:

```
DECLARE 
  -- Local variables here
  strPrev_object          VARCHAR2(30);
  strReturn_type          VARCHAR2(30);
  strProcedure_definition VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  -- This dumps out subprogram definitions.  It doesn't try to build
  -- package scripts; instead, it dumps the package procedures as though they were defined
  -- individually, with package name preceding subprogram name.

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT *
                 FROM USER_ARGUMENTS a
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, MAX(SEQUENCE) AS MAX_SEQUENCE
                               FROM USER_ARGUMENTS
                               GROUP BY PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME)
                   USING (PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME)
                 WHERE PACKAGE_NAME IS NULL AND
                       OBJECT_NAME = '<your package, procedure, or function>'
                 ORDER BY PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_NAME, SEQUENCE)
  LOOP
    strProcedure_definition := NULL;

    IF strPrev_object IS NOT NULL AND
       strPrev_object <> aRow.OBJECT_NAME 
    THEN
      IF strReturn_type IS NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('     );');
      ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('     ) RETURN ' || strReturn_type || ';');
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    END IF;

    IF aRow.SEQUENCE = 1 THEN
      IF aRow.ARGUMENT_NAME IS NULL THEN
        strProcedure_definition := 'FUNCTION ';
        strReturn_type := aRow.DATA_TYPE;
      ELSE
        strProcedure_definition := 'PROCEDURE ';
        strReturn_type := NULL;
      END IF;

      IF aRow.PACKAGE_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN
        strProcedure_definition := strProcedure_definition || aRow.PACKAGE_NAME || '.' || aRow.OBJECT_NAME || '(';
      ELSE
        strProcedure_definition := strProcedure_definition || aRow.OBJECT_NAME || '(';
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strProcedure_definition);
    END IF;

    IF aRow.ARGUMENT_NAME IS NOT NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('     ' || aRow.ARGUMENT_NAME || '  ' ||
                           CASE aRow.IN_OUT WHEN 'IN/OUT' THEN 'IN OUT' ELSE aRow.IN_OUT END || '  ' ||
                           aRow.DATA_TYPE || CASE WHEN aRow.SEQUENCE <> aRow.MAX_SEQUENCE THEN ',' ELSE '' END
                           );
    END IF;

    strPrev_object := aRow.OBJECT_NAME;
  END LOOP;  -- aRow

  IF strReturn_type IS NULL THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('     );');  
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(') RETURN ' || strReturn_type || ';');
  END IF;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks! A modified version of this has solved my requirement. [Cade's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1083652/a-b-cade) answer was also fine, but this suited my use case better. There is a mistake in the query. You have used select *. It should be column names of the inner query

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
SELECT object_name, argument_name, in_out, data_type
FROM user_arguments;
```

Or [all_arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1014.htm#i1573843), if you have the privileges