# I want to find the list of procedures and packages which uses a specific table or view?

Tags: oracle10g

I have a specific oracle DB. I have around 600 procedures and 26 packages in it . I have a view name consider view_1 which was replaced by another view recently as view_2. i want to change the view name from View_1 to View_2 in all the packages and procedure which uses it. can you please get me a solution for this. how can i know the list of procedure and packages which uses this view_1.

thanks in advance,

Comment: Maybe you can use this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819447/get-a-list-of-all-functions-and-procedures-in-an-oracle-database and then limit your concentration to those that contain view_1.  In the end you will probably have a handful of procedures that you have to go through and adjust, unless there is a large number of edits, doing this manually should probably be feasible

Comment: Hi @Brandin the stackoverflow.com/questions/1819447/… is different from this scenario. i want the list of procedures, pakages and functions from a single schema which uses view_1. so that i can replace the View_1 name by View_2

Comment: If you have a list of all procedures, then limit your scope to those that contain View_1 or whatever. It will probably be far fewer than 600

Comment: @brandin i am new to oracle. can you please suggest with possible query to retrive the information. thanks in ADvance

Comment: Yeah there is an example in the link i gave. Just try that first and then if it is too much try to limit it with just the procedures that contain View_1 or whatever

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dba_dependencies` (or `all_dependencies` or `user_dependencies` depending on your privileges and whether you are logged in as the user that owns the schema that has all the objects.

This will show you the owner, object name, and object type of every object in the database that depends on `view_1`.

```
SELECT owner, name, type
  FROM dba_dependencies
 WHERE referenced_owner = <<owner of view_1>>
   AND referenced_name  = 'VIEW_1'
   AND referenced_type  = 'VIEW'
```

If you only care about objects on which you have privileges, you can substitute the `all_dependencies` data dictionary table for `dba_dependencies`.  If you only care about objects in your schema, you can use `user_dependences` but then you'd omit the `owner` column from your projection.

Note that this will only resolve cases where Oracle knows that there are dependencies.  If you have code that is using dynamic SQL to refer to `view_1`, that's not something that Oracle is aware of so that's not something that you can find by querying the data dictionary.  You'd potentially need to manually inspect any pieces of code that are doing that.

If you are replacing one view with another, however, I'd question why you wouldn't just replace the implementation of `view_1` with the implementation of `view_2`.  Why bother going through and modifying every place in your code that references `view_1` when you can just change the implementation of `view_1`?  After all, one of the benefits of having a view layer as an API is that you can change the implementation of the views when the underlying data model changes without needing to touch all the code that depends on the view.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the reply. The implementation of view cannot be changed because we are not owner of the view and we derive the view from other schema. initially our system was setup in such a way that is View_1 goes down our system also goes down . Now we are given an idependent view in theitr schema to avoid this dependency.