# Get list of local procedures in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a couple of local functions/procedures defined in a `DECLARE..BEGIN..END;` block:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE a IS
  BEGIN
    ...
  END;
  PROCEDURE b IS
  BEGIN
    ...
  END;
BEGIN

END;
```

How can I get a list of all defined functions/procedures?
(In this example: ['a', 'b'])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819461/4229270

Comment: @Sinto Unfortunately, this doesn't work for _local_ functions and procedures. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible...But,  If you tell me  why do you want it, we may provide an alternate option.

Comment: I have some test methods, that I want to call within a loop. (And I don't want to create a package for that. It would be overkill in my simple case.)

Comment: How many such procedures do you have '[a,b,c..etc] ". why not simply call all of them by their declared names rather than finding out what procedures were defined?

Comment: Not much, but I have some logic around each call. Would be to much for copy/paste. I think, i will simply define a list of proc-names and iterate over it.

Comment: @Sinto It seams, that it is even not possible to call a local procedure by name :///.

Comment: As far as I know: you can't get that unless you parse the source code

Comment: you get so much more if you have an actual package though

Comment: our java based parser can grab those in SQLDev, but we haven't open sourced that...YET

Comment: PS, it's open sourced now https://github.com/oracle/dbtools-commons so you can see how our parser can find and tag pl/sql elements

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in comments, you are much, much, MUCH better off putting your procedures and functions into a package, and then in your anonymous block, you call those packaged subprograms.

This step will make it much easier to find, fix and maintain your code over time.

Plus, as a stored database object, you can then take advantage of data dictionary views and other DB features to analyze your code. For example, if you want to know the names of all subprograms in a package, or even nested/local subprograms in a single procedure or function, you can use PL/Scope.

```
ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='identifiers:all'
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE my_pkg
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   FUNCTION my_function1
      RETURN NUMBER;

   FUNCTION my_function2
      RETURN VARCHAR2;
END;
/

WITH one_obj_name AS (SELECT 'MY_PKG' object_name FROM DUAL)
    SELECT LPAD (' ', 2 * (LEVEL - 1)) || usage || ' ' || name usages
      FROM (SELECT ai.object_name,
                   ai.usage usage,
                   ai.usage_id,
                   ai.usage_context_id,
                   ai.TYPE || ' ' || ai.name name,
                   ai.line,
                   ai.col
              FROM all_identifiers ai, one_obj_name
             WHERE ai.object_name = one_obj_name.object_name)
START WITH usage_context_id = 0
CONNECT BY PRIOR usage_id = usage_context_id
/

USAGES
-----------------------------------------
DECLARATION PACKAGE MY_PKG  
  DECLARATION FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION1 
    REFERENCE NUMBER DATATYPE NUMBER    
  DECLARATION FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION2 
    REFERENCE CHARACTER DATATYPE VARCHAR2
```

PL/Scope is an incredibly powerful utility, built right into PL/SQL. Check out these resources for more information:

[Philippe Salvisberg's PL/Scope Utilities](https://www.salvis.com/blog/2017/03/17/plscope-utils-utilities-for-plscope-in-oracle-database-12-2/)

[My blog posts on PL/Scope](https://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/search?q=pl%2Fscope)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PL/Scope, if the anonymous PL/SQL block is part of a stored object and you are using an Oracle Database version >= 11.1.

```
ALTER SESSION SET plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p IS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      PROCEDURE a IS
      BEGIN
        NULL;
      END;
      PROCEDURE b IS
      BEGIN
        NULL;
      END;
   BEGIN
      NULL;
   END;
END p;
/

SELECT name 
  FROM user_identifiers
 WHERE object_name = 'P'
   AND usage = 'DEFINITION'
   AND type IN ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION')
   AND line > 1;

NAME                          
------------------------------
A                             
B
```

You need some kind of extraction logic and a PL/SQL parser, if the anonymous PL/SQL block is stored somewhere else.