# How create a query to show all functions and procedures to which I have access? SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I write a query to show all functions and procedures to which I have access. Including the owner of the object as well.?
Oracle SQL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a list of all functions and procedures in an Oracle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819447/get-a-list-of-all-functions-and-procedures-in-an-oracle-database). If you take a glance at a documentation, the tables have an `OWNER` field.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_source
WHERE type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
AND OWNER = ''; -- ENTER YOUR OWNER NAME HERE
```

Or maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM dba_tab_privs
  WHERE TYPE IN ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
  AND (GRANTEE = '' -- ENTER YOUR USER NAME HERE
       OR GRANTEE in (SELECT granted_role
                      FROM dba_role_privs
                      WHERE GRANTEE = '') -- ENTER YOUR USER NAME HERE
```